# How to publish artifacts to Maven Central from a CI build server?

Tags: maven, pgp

I want to publish an artifact to Maven Central from our build server, just like is common practice with internal projects in my company, which are deployed to a local Nexus.

The only difference is that artifacts on Maven Central need to be PGP-signed, before they are accepted.

How do other projects handle this? Do I need to upload my private PGP key and passphrase to the CI server? This doesn't feel right, since a private key usually should never leave my own machine. Should I build releases for Maven Central from my local machine? How does this work in teams where multiple people can publish an artifact?

While there's an [official guide on how to upload artifacts](https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html) and a [guide on working with PGP signatures](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/working-with-pgp-signatures.html), my questions are not covered there.

Comment: first deploying to Central is something doing from a local machine and yes your feeling is right that a PGP key should never leave your own machine. In teams where multiple people can publish each of them has it's own PGP key and signs the appropriate artifacts with it's own key...There could be a way doing a stage of the artifacts into jenkins for example or Nexus and make somehow the final step to central via a trigger where you sign the artifacts than ....but brings the risk with your PGP key...

Comment: Are you going to publish snapshots or releases?  The latter could have the actual final preparation and publishing done outside the CI-server.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm going to publish releases.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for your comment. If you turned this into an answer, I could accept it and mark this question solved. Maybe this is something that’s worth to mention in the official documentation? What do you think? It’s not obvious (at least not for me) and crypto is something that’s easy to get wrong.